# How to mount a filesystem in a read-only environment?

Tags: linux, mount, read-only

I have the problem that my machine turned the root filesystem into readonly mode and remounting it as writeable won't work:

```
# mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda1 /
mount: block device /dev/sda1 is write-protected, mounting read-only
```

I want to copy some data away from that system and I attached a USB drive and tried to mount it:

```
# mount -t ext3 /dev/sdb1 /mnt
mount: /dev/sdb1 already mounted or /mnt busy
```

`/mnt` is an empty directory, so mounting there should usually work, but it seems that having this directory on a readonly filesystem doesn't make it possible to mount something there.

I think there is no activity going on for `/mnt`, since the following command doesn't return any output:

```
# lsof | grep "/mnt" | grep -v grep
```

There is no other partition mounted as the readonly root filesystem at the moment. Is it possible to still get the attached disk into the directory hierarchy somehow?

Comment: Is there anything useful in your logs regarding the fact that your root filesystem was remounted read-only?

Comment: You are using `/dev/sda1` foir the first command and `dev/sdb1` for the second. Is that a mistake?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first error message is telling me that you'll need to reboot - there's something wrong with the disk device itself that the kernel can't resolve without a reboot. If you're booted from SAN, look carefully at your boot LUN and make sure there's nothing wonky with it, or the zoning for the SAN, or the export of the LUN.

Comment: Of course reboot will do, *but* if all the disks, partitions, VGs, LVs, etc. are *not* write-protected, why does the kernel say so? It might be a kernel bug. As I have the same problem, I found out via `strace` that the `mount` system call returns `EROFS` (*Read-only filesystem*). I also did an `fsck` (as the mount is read-only) to find out that the "*contains a filesystem with errors*" does not go away even though `fsck` succeeded.

Comment: FYI: I filed a kernel bug ([Bug 214927 - re-mount read-write (mount -oremount,rw) of read-only filesystem rejected with EROFS, but block device is not read-only](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=214927)).

Comment: After all it seem to be a feature, not a bug. [Comment #3 for Bug 21927](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=214927#c3) explains that.

Answer (score 6):

Set the mount point to anything that is not on the same partition as "/". For example, often the "/tmp" directory or some other directory is a separate partition. Then, it's as simple as creating a temporary mount point:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/mnt
```

and then

```
# mount -t ext3 /dev/sdb1 /tmp/mnt
```

AS long as /tmp is on a separate mountable partition, it completely bypasses any issues you're having with the root partition.

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that the device in question might not be formatted with ext3.

Comment: This worked for me while troubleshooting an AWS OEL instance with a bad root volume, thanks.

Comment: @LondonRob `blkid /dev/sda1` would tell you, however.

Comment: I doubt this will help against "**/dev/sda1 is write-protected**".

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a stale mtab. Try mounting with the -n option.

Comment: As today's Linux has a link from `/etc/mtab` to `/proc/self/mounts`, it's kind of useless. Maybe also `-n` does not have any effect at all (any more).

Answer (score 0):

Apart from /dev/sda1, if there is any separate partition available, say /boot, then create a directory under /boot and mount your usb drive there. What I suspect is /mnt is also part of /. If / is ro, then /mnt mount may not work.

Answer (score -1):

Please format your memory in another filesystem

mkfs.xfs /dev/sdXX
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdXX

or any other filesystem

Comment: Is that just some random thought you had?